# How to organize flutter apps in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

i recently started learning Flutter in andorid studio. while learning i would like to have all my apps sit next to each other in left pane of andoid studio so i can open various apps and examine code without opening and closing projects. also it makes it easy to commit all my learning code in a single github repo. something like below which i did when learning java apps in android studio
https://github.com/maviharjit/AndroidCourse
in this case i had one project and every app was a new module. it worked beautifully for me

however, i can't seem to do the same with Flutter. The challenge that i am facing with flutter is that each app or module or package opens in its own "space" and hence i can only visually examine the code of a single app. i want to be able to see like 10-15 flutter app at the same time in the left pane of android studio. how can i do that? (hope my articulation makes sense)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by a left pane of Android Studio? And I don't think you can open 10-15 flutter apps in the same android studio window. You will have ti use multiple android studio windows. and even if you manage to open 10-15 apps you will stress your computer RAM

Answer (score 1):

Try this it may be what you want...
Go to file in android studio, then hover or click over open recent then your recent projects will be shown all together click on the one you want to open and it will ask same window or new window choos new window so that it will open in a new window and you can see both projects at a time and also compare. Like this you can open as many projects you want